# mongoose query for an array of dictionaries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How do you work with arrays that contain dictionaries? I'm trying to get together all the `post` fields so I can search their text.

My attempts keep going nowhere using `mongo` shell.

```
User.Blog().find({}).where('post').in(writing).exec(function (err, result) {
  //do something with results
}); // doesn't work
```

**schema** (edit: fixed from @JAM comments)

```
var blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  group:  String,
  writing: [{
        post: String,
        name : Number
        }]
});

var Blog = mongoose.model('Blog', blogSchema);
```

**Update: adding json data and the command to put data in mongodb using mongo shell:**

```
{
  group:  "Design Writing",
  writing: [{
        post: "A very very very short post.",
        name:  10
  }, {
        post: "An early morning post about everything.",
        name:  11
  }]
}
```

**Or, here as one line to insert into a db in the collection named `my_collection`: **

```
db.my_collection.insert( {group:  "Design Writing", writing: [{post: "A very very very short post.",name:  10}, {post: "An early morning post about everything.",name:  11}]} )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objects in your `writing` array is treated as [sub/embedded-documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html). This means that they are assigned an `_id` when they are stored in the database.

So, there is a few ways you can query `Blog`s based on these sub documents:

```
var ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

// Assuming these objects are in the 'writing' array of a Blog
var postObject = { post: 'some text', name: 10 },
    postObjectWithId = { _id: new ObjectId(), post: 'some text', name: 10 };

// Example #1 Works!
Blog.find({'writing.post': postObject.post})
    .exec(function(err, res){ onBlogResult("Ex#1", err, res) });

// Example #2 Works!
Blog.find({})                        
    .where('writing').in([postObjectWithId])
    .exec(function(err, res){ onBlogResult("Ex#2", err, res) });

// Example #3 Works - its the same as example #2!
Blog.find({'writing': { $in: [ postObjectWithId ]}})
    .exec(function(err, res){ onBlogResult("Ex#3", err, res) });

// Example #4 Fails because of missing _id on postObject!
Blog.find({'writing': { $in: [ postObject ]}})
    .exec(function(err, res){ onBlogResult("Ex#4", err, res) });
```

As you see, you can only `find` objects with an array containing an element using `in` if you have the full object (including the `_id`).

You can view the whole source on this [**GIST**](https://gist.github.com/jmyrland/5578516) - Test it out for yourself :)

Hope this helps :)

[**Read the mongoose docs here**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html).

Comment: What goes in "postObj"? I tried 'post' but that doesn't work - closer but something is off. I'm getting confused by the chaining. (Yeh, I typed the schema wrong when making the example.)

Comment: postObj example `{ post: "heyho", name: 1 }` - as your schema specifies. I think that works.

Comment: Hmmm. Still  not working. The find() works, but I can't penetrate deeper into the structure using mongoose. I'll keeping trying, though I've tried a dozen version. I CAN pull out what I need by explicitly writing out in the exec function this:  `var just_the_post = result[0]['writing'][0]['post']` ;D

Comment: oh, ok. Then try `.where('writing.post').equals(postObj.post)` - let me know if that works :)

Comment: eeeks. sorry, do you mean then like this? `find({}).where('writing.post').equals({ post: "heyho", name: 1 }.post)` ? I'm not clear about where postObj comes from!

Comment: Slide 26 has the same data structure to what I have but the author has no example in the entire slide deck on how to handle it getting into the array of dictionaries `{'comments' :[ {}, {} ]`    http://www.slideshare.net/YnonPerek/getting-started-with-mongodb-and-mongoose

Comment: I think my schema is wrong. I need to declare things differently. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html

Comment: @cathy.sasaki ok, forget about `postObj` it was just an example :p Yes you could do it like `{ post: "heyho", name: 1 }.post` as well - but then again you could just type `"heyho"` directly :p

Comment: Eeeeeks again. I'm still not getting it to work. But I updated the question with example json data. I might do some background reading and come back to this in a few days so my mind clears. Considering doing JSON data without "array dictionaries" and focus on dictionaries of dictionaries, which let you do the dot notation easily deep into the structure. Still brooding on it!! :D

Comment: I'll write up a short working example soon, and post it here when I'm done :)

Comment: @cathy.sasaki Updated my answer now :) Hope that helps you

Comment: Awesome. Very very instructive! I just tested it myself. The gist is great. So happy the answer got pinned down. :D